# How to make vertical scroll content with FlexBox

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I am trying to implement a scroll box with flex
The Box element with the id=scroll is taking the available space and the content is overflowing the Box
How can i make the Box be overflow=auto and making the content scrollable
spending hours to understand what is going on with flex
here is a real example : https://codesandbox.io/s/flex-with-scroll-2cf9d

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Box, Grid, CssBaseline } from "@material-ui/core";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Box height="100vh" flexDirection="column" display="flex" bgcolor="blue">
      <CssBaseline />
      <Box p={2}>
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Box bgcolor="white">
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
            </Box>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Box bgcolor="white">
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
            </Box>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Box>
      <Box flex={1} flexDirection="column" display="flex" p={2}>
        <Grid style={{ display: "flex", flex: 1 }} container spacing={3}>
          <Grid style={{ display: "flex", flex: 1 }} item xs={6}>
            <Box id='scroll' flex={1} bgcolor="white">
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
              <div>ssss</div>
            </Box>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6} />
        </Grid>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow auto on the Box component.

```
<Box overflow="auto" flex={1} flexDirection="column" display="flex" p={2}>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/flex-with-scroll-82h9c

The below image is my understanding of the layout you're describing. If that's not what you're looking for then you may need to add more clarity to your question.

[image]

Comment: still the content of the id=scroll will take more then available space i want it to take no more from 100vh and if so be scroll

Comment: Posted codesandbox with overflow auto, it appears to be doing what you describe you want.

Comment: ?? the codesendbox is not working the box with the id scroll taking more then 100vh and the content is overlowing the container box

Comment: I put a yellow border around the outer Box and a red on the id scroll Box. As you can see, the outer Box is taking only 100vh and the contents of the id scroll Box are scrollable.

Comment: I will try to formulate my question in a better way
I need only one of the <Grid item> to be in the scroll and not all the <Grid container>